# помогите с кодом в selenium ide

Tags: java, консоль, if, return, execute

Подскажите, можно ли в Selenium ide при наличии определенного элемента на странице, например кнопка "Выполнить", задать команду для возврата к ранее исполненной команде, например №3, до тех пор пока кнопка "Выполнить" не пропадет на странице?

```
if (selenium.isElementPresent("//button[contains(.,'Выполнить')]") ==true) 
{executeScript = 'return 3'}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Добавьте метку языка программирования в вопрос.